# How can I wait till the send command completes its execution in expect script

Tags: timeout, wait, expect

My code look like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set $somelocation "cd /somelocation"
set perlScriptCommand "perl runScript.pl abc xyz\r"

spawn ssh uid@IP
expect "Password: "
send "$pwd\r"
sleep 2

#change directory in the remote
send "$somelocation"

#run a perl script in the remote
send $perlScriptCommand

# **I want to make the script wait till the perl command is completed in remote

#once the previous step is completed I want to exit the remote session
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

I want to wait till the send command (perl script execution in remote) completes.
Then I want to exit the remote session.

I have tried by passing the commands along with ssh. Still it doesn't wait for the perl script to complete.

```
set somelocation "cd /somelocation"

spawn ssh uid@IP "$somelocation; $perlScriptCommand"
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's an answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351695/how-to-make-expect-to-wait-until-another-script-finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `send` something, you need to `expect` something. When you find yourself putting `sleep` into an expect script, then your expect patterns may not be matching and need to be adjusted.

I'll assume your prompt ends with "dollar+space"

```
set prompt {\$ $}
set somelocation "cd /somelocation"
set perlScriptCommand "perl runScript.pl abc xyz"

spawn ssh uid@IP
expect "Password: "
send -- "$pwd\r"
expect -re $prompt

send -- "$somelocation\r"
expect -re $prompt

# disable the timeout so the perl script can take as long as it needs
set timeout -1
send -- "$perlScriptCommand\r"
expect -re $prompt

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

While developing an expect script, run it with `expect -d` so you can verify that your expect patterns are matching correctly.